# change dataField in jquery line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery chart to draw line chart and i need to add some string to dataField.I'm getting data from data base and include that in dataField.my graph is creating correctly and i only need to change dataField.

```
categoryAxis: {
    text: 'Category Axis',
    textRotationAngle: 90,
    dataField: '{$this->graphField_Date}',
    showTickMarks: true,
    valuesOnTicks: false,
    tickMarksInterval: 1,
    tickMarksColor: '#888888',
    unitInterval: 1,
    gridLinesInterval: 1,
    gridLinesColor: '#888888',
    axisSize: 'auto'
},
```

`{$this->graphField_Date}` gets the week numbers of given period and i need to add "week"  after the number how can do that.(eg 1 week,2 week)currently i'm getting only 1,2,3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
categoryAxis.dataField = '{$this->graphField_Date}' + ' week'
```

**Edit:**

You could manipulate the DOM after the data has been loaded. In the success function of you ajax call ( if you are using ajax ), or just after the data has been added to the DOM add:

```
$('.dateFieldClass').append(' week');
```

This is assuming you have the date field data in an element with the class dateFieldClass

Comment: i've added another idea